# C - Variable has incomplete type "struct ..."

Tags: c, struct, typedef, definition, incomplete-type

I have a `container.h` file and a `container.c` file.

In the `container.h` file, I've written the following:

```c
typedef struct Container Container;
```

And the following in the `container.c` file:

```c
#include "container.h"

typedef struct Container
{
  size_t item_count;
} Container;
```

However, I keep getting the `variable has incomplete type "struct Container"` error. Is this something that has to do with using `extern` with struct or something?

Edit: I have compiled the following as a library and `#include`-d it in another `main.c` file where I wrote the following:

```c
#include "library.h"

int main()
{
  Container ctnr = { 0 };

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that the exact and complete code that produces the problem? It doesn't have any variable declarations so I don't think it is. Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as the exact and full error msg (including line number).

Comment: @kaylum I missed a part probably I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the only translation unit that knows the structure definition is the translation unit with the file `container.c`.

If any other translation unit needs to know the structure definition then the compiler will issue an error because the structure definition is not available. You need to place the structure definition in the header.

That is the translation unit with the function main

```
#include "library.h"

int main()
{
  Container ctnr = { 0 };

  return 0;
}
```

needs to know the structure definition to allocate memory for the object `ctnr`. But the structure definition is not available. So the compiler at least does not know how much memory to allocate.
Also there is no need to use two typedef(s) with the same name. One of typedef(s) is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm really a noobie here, so I didn't quite get what you meant or rather why that is happening. I will try to do some research on your answer to understand it, so thank you, but I can't accept it yet.

Comment: @xdraxulisx Reread the answer. There all is written enough clear.

Comment: _After some reading_: I think you meant I should define the `struct` in the header file. I've thought of this, in fact I've thought of creating a header-only library, but doesn't it add a lot of overhead? I read that somewhere, and I need the most performance I could get.

Comment: @xdraxulisx Yes> I wrote in teh answer that you have to place the structure definition in the header.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, It's much clearer now!

Comment: I'm asking a lot, but how could I include the `.c` file? I'm already including the library in the build `library.a`, so what's the problem here? I can't work header-only.

Comment: @xdraxulisx This is a bad idea Declarations that used by several compilations units should be in a header.